# Text becoming fuzzy when Cyrillic is allowed

Tags: cyrillic

When compiling

```
\documentclass{article}
% For Cyrillic:
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
  This text is fuzzy (размытые очертания).
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

And when I remove Cyrillic

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  All letters have crisp edges.
 \end{document}
```

I get
[image]

Is there an easy modification of the first document that would make the edges crisp?  I usually need just a few words in Cyrillic, and making the whole document fuzzy is too high a price to pay for me.

**Added on 23 December 2018:** Thank you to all who answered my question.  Unfortunately, installing CM-Super did not work for me.  Normally MiKTeX installs packages on the fly, but for CM-Super I was getting error messages.  Since I need just a few words in Cyrillic (in the bibliography) and often share my files with colleagues and publishers, installing CM-Super would be an overkill.  My solution in the end was:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{T2Aenc.def}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newenvironment{cyr}
  {\begingroup\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont}
  {\endgroup}
\begin{document}
  The English fonts are vector and Cyrillic bitmap
  (\begin{cyr}последнее мне не важно\end{cyr}).
\end{document}
```

The Russian font is still bitmap, but I can live with it.

Comment: Install the cm-super package.

Comment: If you load `fontspec` and compile with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can use any OpenType or TrueType font, for example, Latin Modern.